# Android sprite touch event gives error

Tags: android, andengine

I have the following code:

```
Sprite sPlayer = new Sprite(800 / 2, 480 / 2,
playerTextureRegion,
engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent tEvent, final float X,
    final float Y)
    {
        if ( tEvent.isActionDown() )
        // Some code
        return true;
    };
};

gameScene.registerTouchArea(sPlayer);
gameScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
gameScene.attachChild(sPlayer);
```

1. When I run it, it gives me error and the app closes
2. I see most people using `gameScene.setTouchBindingEnabled(True)`
   instead of `gameScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);` but Eclipse doesn't recognize this one and I can't import any package for it. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Can you please post the error it gives you?

Comment: It doesn't give me a specific error. When I run it on my phone, when I click on sprite it closes and it say the app had to close

Comment: Connect it to your computer and watch for the LogCat logs, you will get there the messages.

Comment: Finally I found the problem. In the if statement I had a line with Toast to display a message. Probably, I cant use Toast. Without the Toast everything is ok. Do you know why?

Comment: can you edit your question/ask a new one to see the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, you need to use the function `runOnUiThread`

```
YourActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

or, you can use the function `toastOnUiThread` :

> YourActivity.toastOnUiThread(msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

where `YourActivity` is your activity in the game(just pass a reference to it)